# Help with Ubuntu 22.04 and realtek wifi driver

Tags: drivers, wireless, live-cd

I am absolutely stumped as to how to get my realtek 8821ce driver onto a backup USB drive. I have tried everything from downloading/copying/installing binaries, dependencies, source, using Ventoy, Startup Disk Creator, yadda yadda.
I just want to have a USB stick that I can reinstall the OS iso *AND* have wifi out of the box to get everything else set up.

Yes, I am using Timeshift for system backups, and Deja-Dup (Ubuntu Backups) for home backups.

But I want a backup of the backup, if things go really sideways.

I have an ASUS VivoBook with no ethernet connector.

I have successfully done the initial install using an Android phone with Internet Sharing, which worked great. But what if i lose/break my phone? no cable? Don't pay my bill? Stuck in a mineshaft?

Point is, I want a CONCRETE solution to reinstall Ubuntu and have WiFi drivers.
Any help?

Comment: ANY currently supported Ubuntu releases supports your WiFi out of the box. It may not be with the best driver but is good enough to get you connected so then you can install the better `rtl8821ce-dkms`. And even if that wasn't the case you'd only need a temporary internet connection for SECONDS in order to install the package.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Um, no it doesn't.... Why else would I be asking this question? I've tried using 22.04.1 (the latest) iso from a USB and no wifi....

Comment: Having installed 22.04 recently in a laptop that has that WiFi I **know** it does. Not sure if it works with Secure Boot because I routinely disable it. And again all it takes is seconds with a temporary internet connection (USB tethering from any phone with a data plan is enough). If you want to do it the hard way then include the package and all its dependencies, install the dependencies then the package. The end results is the same.

Comment: I know I can use my phone, just wanted to see if there was a thumbdrive-only solution. I'm not very knowledgeable on Secure Boot, but I will investigate this further to see if that's my problem. Thanks.